# Javascript-putting birthdays in order from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this Javascript below, and I know that there is probably a better way of doing what I have done, so if you would like to share a better way, please do and I will definitely use it.

```
var Apeople = ["bob", "joe", "jane", "mike", "henry", "alex"];
var Abdays = ["08/20", "01/23", "04/19", "08/16", "01/08", "04/02"];
```

Apeople and Abdays line up with each other, so Janes birthday is 04/19.

I know I'm not supposed to use eval() so if you know of a better way please tell me.

```
var mnths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
for(i=0; i<mnths.length; i++){
   eval("var "+mnths[i]+" = []");
}

for(i=0; i<Abdays.length; i++){
   var ab = Abdays[i];
   if(ab.substring(0,1) == "0"){
      var mn = ab.substring(1,2); //month number without 0 before it
   } else {
      var mn = ab.substring(0,2); //month number if 11 or 12
   }
   eval(""+mnths[mn-1]+".push(i)");
}
```

Now I have `January=[1,4] April=[2,5] August=[0,3]`. I did this so I can find out whos name goes with what birthday.

For example `Apeople[January[0]]` would be joe and `Abdays[January[0]]` would be 01/23.

What I need to do is put each months entries in order by which comes first going by the birthdays. `Abdays[January[0]]` is 01/23 but `Abdays[January[1]]` is 01/08 so they should be swapped.

As I am typing this I am thinking that I probably should have used JSON.

So what I need help with is putting the birthdays in order while still being able to tell which birthday goes to which name, and at the same time possibly finding a better way to write this code.

Comment: If you converted those `mm/dd` values to native JS timestamps, you could simply use a standard array sort call in JS to get them in order. As is, you've got a lot of extra pointless work to do because you're not exploiting native capabilities.

Comment: BTW: You're eval is not util. Don't use eval to do that. `mnths[mn-1].push(i)` will totaly work. In most case, eval can and must be avoided. AND you don't do `eval("var "+mnths[i]+" = []");` you're mixing array and object here...

Comment: @MarcB Yes, but if I sorted just the birthdays, I wouldn't know which name went with each birthday anymore because they wouldn't line up.

Comment: @dievardump So if I get rid of the eval in `eval(""+mnths[mn-1]+".push(i)");` and just do `mnths[mn-1].push(i)` I could also get rid of the first eval, correct?
Edit: I tried doing just `mnths[mn-1].push(i)` and get the error `Error: TypeError: mnths[mn - 1].push is not a function`

Comment: Btw, `ab.substring(0,1)` can be substituted with `ab.charAt(0)` [fnctn](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp).

Comment: JSON have zero relevance to this question.

Comment: @Tomjr260 yes you have an error because you first loop was not good. you can't do `var myArray[i] = [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the`Abdays` array like this.

```
Abdays = Abdays.sort(function(a, b){
   var d1 = new Date(a + " 2010");
   var d2 = new Date(b + " 2010");
   return d1 > d2;
});
```

I randomly selected 2010. You will have to modify this, add more conditions if you need and write code to sort `Apeople` according to sorted `Abdays` .

UPDATE:

Quickly written. You can find better ways, but hope this helps

```
var map = {};
for(var i=0 ; i < Apeople.length; i++){
   map[Abdays[i]] = Apeople[i];
}

Abdays = Abdays.sort(function(a, b){      
   var d1 = new Date(a + " 2010");
   var d2 = new Date(b + " 2010");
   return d1 > d2;
});

for(var i=0 ; i < Apeople.length; i++){
   Apeople[i] = map[Abdays[i]];
}

console.log(Apeople, Abdays);
```

Comment: Yes. That is the best way to do it. Then you can sort array easily like this maintaining name-date relation.

Comment: Yes. This works perfect, however how would I sort Apeople according to the sorted Abdays?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way of doing it. This makes use of a custom sort function.

```
​
var birthdays = [];

​birthdays[0] = { "name": "Bob", "month": 8, "day": 1 };
birthdays[1] = { "name": "John", "month": 4, "day": 2 };
birthdays[2] = { "name": "Jane", "month": 1, "day": 15 };

birthdays.sort( function( a, b ) { 

    if(a["month"] < b["month"] ) return -1;
    if(a["month"] > b["month"] ) return 1;
    if( a["day"] < b["day"] ) return -1;
    if( a["day"] > b["day"] ) return 1;

    return 0; //they are the same
});
```

The added advantage is that you can modify the sort function to suit your needs.

Comment: This also looks great. Between the two answers, I should be able to work something out. Thanks!